# useSWR integration with pagination on backend

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query, swr

When page changes, new query is created and it's data is set to initialData.
In this case user sees initialData before new query data is fetched:

```
import React from "react";

import fetch from "../lib/fetch";
import useSWR from "swr";

function Component({ initialData }) {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);
  const { data } = useSWR(
    `/api/data?page=${page}`,
    { initialData }
  );
  // ...
}
Component.getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const data = await fetch('/api/data?page=1');
  return { initialData: data };
};
```

My issue is that initialData is used as a fallback every time I query for new data:

[image]

Do you have any ideas on how I can prevent this flicker?

Comment: interesting that you tagged this with `react-query`, because I don't think its an issue that exists in `react-query` ;)

Comment: Initially I was using `react-query` but moved to `swr` because of this issue - unfortunately, both have the same issue. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in react-query, I think there are multiple ways to avoid this:

1. `keepPreviousData: true`

this is the main way how to do pagination, also reflected in the [docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/paginated-queries#better-paginated-queries-with-keeppreviousdata) as well as the [examples](https://react-query.tanstack.com/examples/pagination).

It will make sure that when a query key changes, the data from the previous queryKey is kept on the screen while the new fetch is taking place. The resulting object will have an `isPreviousData` flag set to `true`, so that you can e.g. disable the next button or show a little loading spinner next to it while the transition is happening. It is similar in ux what react suspense is going to give us (somewhen).

2. initialData function

`initialData` accepts a function as well, and you can return `undefined` if you don't want initial data to be present. You could tie this to your page being the first page for example:

```
function Component({ initialData }) {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);
  const { data } = useQuery(
    ['page', id],
    () => fetchPage(id),
    { initialData: () => page === 1 ? initialData : undefined }
  );
}
```

keep in mind that you will have a `loading` spinner then while transitioning, so I think this is worse than approach 1.

3. since your `initialData` comes from the server, you can try hydrating the whole queryClient. See [the docs on SSR](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/ssr#using-hydration).

---

`initialData` works very well with `keepPreviousData`, so here is a codesandbox fork of the example from the doc where `initialData` is used (solution 1). I think this is the best take: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-murdock-tz22o?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: Thank you, this a great reply.